# Rewrite Lambda function to custom keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

to use LSTM in TfLite I would need to rewrite Lambda layer to a tf keras custom Layer object so that it can hold weights (because Lambda layer cannot do that). I am not quite sure how to that with the example here. Could anyone lend me a helping hand and show me how to rewrite correctly into a [custom layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models)?

```
def buildLstmLayer(inputs):

  lstm_cells = []

  lstm_cells.append(TFLiteLSTMCell(256, forget_bias=0, name='rnn0'))
  lstm_cells.append(TFLiteLSTMCell(128, forget_bias=0, name='rnn1'))
  lstm_layers = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(lstm_cells)

  outputs, _ = dynamic_rnn(
      lstm_layers,
      inputs,
      dtype='float32',
      time_major=True)

  return outputs
```

Comment: Can you use a `tf.keras.RNN` layer? The Tensorflow page says `dynamic_rnn` is deprecated: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn

Comment: If not, just let the cells outside the lambda function. The only thing that needs to be created inside the lamdba is `dynamic_rnn` function.